# What is the difference between "pretty" and "handsome" in this context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

> She has a fine face—originally of a character that would be rather called very pretty than handsome, but improved into classicality by the acquired expression of her fashionable state. *Bleak House* *by* *Charles Dickens*

Does "pretty" mean more feminine here? Or does it mean she is pretty but not attractive "handsome".

Comment: Sort of related: [Can you still call a woman "handsome"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/17108/103888)

Comment: You can also be pretty handsome, but not handsome pretty...

Comment: The best modern translation is very simple:  **"she was cute rather than beautiful"**.  It's that simple.  "Gorgeous" is another modern translation of "handsome" usage in that era.

Answer (score 17):

To get a better idea of what the meaning was when Dickens wrote, I am giving the relevant definitions from Walker's *Critical Pronouncing Dictionary* from 1831, twenty years before Dickens wrote *Bleak House*.

> [**Handsome**:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_critical_pronouncing_dictionary_Also_A/11BiAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=handsome) Beautiful, graceful; elegant.

> [**Pretty**:](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_critical_pronouncing_dictionary_Also_A/11BiAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=pretty) Neat, elegant; beautiful without grandeur or dignity; it is used in a kind of diminutive contempt in poetry and in conversation.

So you can see the main difference is that something that is handsome has grandeur or dignity, while something that is merely pretty lacks these qualities.

Comment: An interesting topic. There might have been an element of class in Walker's definitions: a duchess can be handsome; her maid might be pretty. There may be some sexism, too - someone (a man) once said 'You can keep all your beautiful women; I'd prefer a pretty one'. I once read an account of a male journalist's interview with the model Kate Moss, at the peak of her career. He wrote that beforehand he was nervous of meeting her, because her found 'beautiful' women intimidating, but when she came in the room, he was reassured because she was not beautiful, but 'stunningly pretty'.

Answer (score 16):

A pretty girl or woman is attractive in a 'delicate' way, as the dictionaries put it. *Handsome* is nowadays more often used to describe men than women, but when used of a woman it means "fine-looking in a dignified way" (Collins Dictionary).

Since Lady Dedlock married a baronet and began to mix with people of high social status, she has acquired a dignified manner which makes people more inclined to describe her as 'handsome'.

Answer (score 2):

In modern language, "handsome" is normally only used to describe males. However, women are sometimes described as 'handsome' to mean they were "*striking and imposing in good looks rather than conventionally pretty*". It usually describes a more mature, statuesque appearance that is still attractive but perhaps not what everyone would think of as such.

This use is considered out of date, but is occasionally used and, of course, you find it in older literature such as the Charles Dickens novel you are reading.

Even with a definition of the word, it is quite difficult to describe and even imagine exactly how Dickens saw this character. Not only is beauty subjective, but the normative societal expectation of beauty changes over time, too. It is difficult to say precisely what physical characteristics made a Victorian man describe a woman as 'handsome', but suffice to say it meant different from the general view of the time.

Comment: From early middle age on, the Matron was quite a handsome woman. She would never have been called pretty, but nor was she ugly.

Comment: I don't know that *handsome* implies more maturity. "Emma Woodhouse, handsome, clever, and rich  ...  had lived nearly twenty-one years in the world." Austen's heroine is only **twenty years old**.

Comment: *"In modern language, "handsome" is normally only used to describe males"* literally every woman I associate with I flatter by telling them how handsome they are.  I feel the "normally" is a stretch.  (I also constantly use the word "handsome" to describe animals, houses, cars, kitchen renovation.) (I've never once used it regarding a man as I'm not in to men.)

Comment: @Fattie Well, you're saying that *you* use it... that's 1 person. I based what I said on what I've heard for the last 49 years living in Britain. It's rare. I can't remember it ever being said in earnestness. I did a quick ngram and use of it fell during the last century to almost nothing. There is a slight upsurge in recent literature, but when you play with the dialect settings it seems like certain English dialects are skewing that. It isn't said in Britain. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=handsome+woman&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

Comment: @Fattie - Surely you don't have to be 'into' someone to recognise objectively that they are good-looking?

Comment: @KateBunting  I'm an old-days "ladies man". Like, you know, say, Dean Martin :)  [Thank God, in the current "ultra-possible" socio-political sphere, it's *absolutely* OK to be *anything* you want and nobody *dares* comment on it - you can be  a therian, a "ladies man", an acrotomophiliast - whatever. When I lived through say the 90s, you'd get flack for many such "categories". Whoo 2020s!] So I rarely speak to men for any reason. But sure, I've described Sting or David Beckham or Prince as "handsome"; so yes, when discussing public figures. I suppose I meant "in personal direct speech."

Comment: (It's astonishing how off-track these comments can get.)   The point is, as also @verbose made an excellent point, IMO this answer is off-base in suggesting that *in the period under discussion* it carried a sense mature, statuesque. As the best comment on the page mentions, The best modern translation is very simple: "she was cute rather than beautiful".

Comment: @Fattie - Only to Americans (Oxford Languages gives the 'sexually attractive' sense of 'cute' as 'informal North American;).

Comment: @fattie That wasn't what I intended - I said that was the meaning, and that the word isn't used as much today. I didn't suggest the meaning had changed over time. What I tried to do was use modern language to define this older term. But this is a particularly difficult example, because not only is beauty subjective, but the normative societal expectation of beauty changes over time, too. It is difficult to say precisely what physical characteristics made a Victorian man describe a woman as 'handsome'.

Comment: @KateBunting - But wait (1) I didn't actually know that; and I'm not sure I agree with that dictionary writer, on two counts. (a) "cute" does not mean sexually attractive (as say "hot" does); rather it means kawaii, happy-smiley, youthfully fashionable, indeed often used about kids. (b) I don't really see much difference regionally is usage of "cute". Moreover (2) in my grand translation *The best modern translation is very simple: "she was cute rather than beautiful"* I can see that (what a failure) you for example read it not as I meant it ...

Comment: My reading of the original and my (attempted) translation is "The woman is presentable, not pock-marked, looks OK, but she is not hot and sexually attractive, she's not a smokin' hot broad, not drop-dead gorgeous." The writer is disparagingly  saying and thinking she looks "ok but not that great".   {Aside - no actual ladies' man ever thinks such a thing; clearly Dickens was not a success with the ladies. :O } The key point is IMO (in that period) handsome plain meant "attractive, beautiful", there was no implication of "stately, old, matronly" etc - as in the present-day usage. Anyway.

Comment: @Astralbee I'm afraid I disagree.  (Also there's a typo? in your second sentence "are/were" ..?)  The situation IMO is straightforward. The word has **changed meaning** (which is a completely normal, ubiquitous thing). It used to mean "beautiful, good looking, attractive". It now means "elegant, mature, older".  As you say in your comment *"I didn't suggest the meaning had changed over time."* IMO that is incorrect.

Comment: @Fattie - But 'very pretty' doesn't mean '[only] presentable'!

Comment: @KateBunting if u mean today, not per the passage, that's a good point, but I fear we've gone beyond the point where we're discussing not only extremely subtle differences, but interpretations of what Dickens specifically meant, not to mention, doing all that in two eras comparatively.  This is just as difficult as discussing subtle "translations" in modern languages, who knows what the hell it would mean "in English" if we were both Japanese and you called me a gyaru.  .. (yet another cont.)

Comment: .. Bottom line, purely IMO (based on reading vast amounts of Victorian junk - I don't know what else it could be based on) "handsome" was simply a word for "beautiful" (horses, dames, whatever) and did *not* carry the modern connotation "old, dignified".  I'm worn out!

Answer (score 0):

The best example I can think of the connotation of this word in modern English is from 1993 (already more than three decades ago), and I remember thinking how odd it was to hear anyone call a woman “handsome” back when it aired.

It was from the episode “Tapestry” of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.  The premise is that the captain of the Enterprise gets a second chance to live through something that happened to him in his twenties, and react like the older, more cautious man he is now.  This leads to a conversation at the bar with a woman he met the night before/decades ago:

> **PENNY:** What's wrong? I don't look as attractive to you as I did last night?
>
> **PICARD:** No, no, not at all. I think you're a very handsome woman.
>
> **PENNY:** Handsome. That's something you say to old ladies.
>
> **PICARD:** You're certainly not an old lady.
>
> [she throws her drink in his face]

I think “handsome woman” connotes that she looks androgynous, more than old. But I’d consider it rude to call a woman that (except in some very unusual context).  From a non-native speaker, it would probably sound like a mistake.

It’s also rude, in most contexts, to call an adult man “pretty.”  (Especially for another man.)  I’ve most often heard this used of a “bishonen” androgenous manga/anime character.  Using a word associated with the opposite gender of someone suggests that they invert gender stereotypes (and this is one of the few times where describing a woman in the same language you would use to compliment a man is not a compliment).

Comment: _'to call an adult man "pretty"_ - A joke meme that UK men use about the risk of  being arrested for anything is 'I can't go to jail! A pretty boy like me! (etc)'. I have got laughs from it myself.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey In that context, the implication being that gay men would find him attractive. (Since this is a site for learners.)

Comment: the 'joke' relies on the meme that in male prisons, a prisoner does not have to be gay to force a younger, smaller, weaker fellow inmate to submit to sexual advances - also a similar one that men confined together e.g. on long sea voyages may use each other for sex.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey “No man would enlist in the Royal Navy who could contrive to be sent to prison. A boat is a prison, with the risk of drowning.”

Comment: Ah yes, Doctor Johnson.

Comment: @Davislor Prison sex isn't about being gay or finding someone attractive. It's a power dynamic. The powerful inmates are raping the weaker ones, to maintain their position at the top of the hierarchy.

Comment: @Barmar Discussion of whether the the joke is accurate or not is off-topic, so I’m reluctant to respond. However, the claim you made is an urban legend. The original source was a study by A. Nicholas Groth in 1979, “Men who Rape: The Psychology of the Offender.” He said all “forcible rapists” have three motivations: power, anger, and sexual arousal. In interviews with convicted rapists, he found that 55% of his sample said they were more motivated by power than the other two. Through a game of Telephone, that became the sweeping claim that rape is all about power.

Comment: @Davislor - can you stop with the facts crap? This is the internet.